# Problem with mysql update on 16.04.2

Tags: dpkg, mysql

I'm having problems following an update to MySQL. Dpkg hangs for a long time configuring mysql-server-5.7.17 before eventually giving an error message "subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1". Whenever I run dpkg it complains about mysql-server-5.7.17 not being configured. When I run

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

to try and clean things up it gives this error and leaves MySQL not running. If I then try to run MySQL it takes forever before saying it is running but it appears not to actually run - at least, nothing can communicate with it. The only way I can persuade it to run at the moment is to reboot the box.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL and it hasn't made any difference. Any ideas what is going on and how I sort this out?

In /var/crash I've got bind9.0.crash and mysql-server-5.7.0.crash. These were both created at the same time which appears to be when the problem started. Happy to post extracts from these if it would help.

Comment: Did you ever managed to find a solution?

Comment: Yes thanks. I uninstalled again and this time I removed the database completely (having backed up the bits I needed). I then reinstalled and restored the tables I'd backed up. Everything now seems to be working fine.